# Secure cookies Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to secure cookies in asp.net core. Because for now i have cookies in just plain text and everyone can get the data from inspector in browser. Does some handy  solution exists for it, so it can encrypt and decrypt cookie value before processing?

```
context.Response.Cookies.Append("name", "Tom");
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added

Comment: Why don't you store these informations on session?

Comment: Don't store secrets or sensitive data on the client. End of story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to encrypt and decrypt string and simple one of them is using `IDataProtector`.

```
private IDataProtector _protector;

public AccessController(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
{
    _protector = provider.CreateProtector("MySecretKey");
}

public void ActionResult Index()
{
    var protectedName = _protector.Protect("Tom");

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("name", protectedName);
   .
   . 
   .
}
```

and use `_protector.UnProtect(encryptedString)` to decrypt string.

Comment: Won't this will fail if you are using a server farm or if the site is moved to a different server? I.e. you won't be able to read the value of the cookie if site is relocated.

Comment: @Sha this is true. But avoidable. You just need to specify a shared key-ring: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @pimbrouwers - Yeah, I just want to avoid all that complexity.